# I modified a template file and now can't remember how

Tags: custom-templates

Yes I know - very foolish but hoping someone will take pity on me!

This is the my screen when entering a contribution or registering for an event while logged in.
I customised it to include the text 'PLEASE PAUSE FOR A MOMENT AND READ THIS - If you are entering a session record, please click on "WANT TO DO THIS FOR A DIFFERENT PERSON" 
Now I want to revert the default but can't remember the file I edited
I've searched all the files in my custom templates directory - heaven forfend I edited core! (although then I guess an upgrade could fix my problem)
Thanks all
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This could potentially be done via Word Replacement - so check there too.

Comment: Onya Pete! I did in fact do it the easy way. Cheers mate.

Comment: I did in fact not change core or templates. I did it in word replacement. So if anyone wants to change the "not you or wish to register another person" that's an easy place to do it.

Comment: Can you mark his as the answer so this doesn't stay in limbo as unanswered? There's a gray checkbox under the vote count to the left you can click.

Answer (score 2):

do a search on your text "PLEASE PAUSE FOR A MOMENT" on your website/civicrm folder, it should tell you which file it is

I would strongly recommend you to write custom extension for these kind of manipulation, it's way safer than using custom template (as in, less issue when you upgrade), and way way safer to modify the core ;)

Comment: I completely agree with this, what you are doing is a bit risky....

Answer (score 0):

An upgrade would indeed fix your problem:-) What operating system and browser are you using? If you are using Firefox then you could right click on the page and view the source code of the page. If you then search for .tpl you should find the starting template of the page? You probably either modified that one or one of the templates it includes with the {include}.

Comment: I looked at the source code - no tpl mentioned?

Comment: The suggestion from Xavier makes sense. If that does not work, expand a little and explain what you try to do step by step.